# Switch Names from one side to other

Tags: powershell

I have to set description to a list of sames provided in csv format.
I know I need samaccountnames so i am trying to pull up samaccount from named, unfortunately the names in csv are in reverse order with a header as name
example
Name
Snow, Jon
Starc,arya
lannister,jamie

In a nutshell, I tried

```
Import-Csv C:\list.csv | 
foreach { 
$_.Name = "{1}, {0}" -f ($_.Name -split ', ') 
$_
```

No luck, any help is appreciated.
The names should come as -

```
Jon snow
Arya starc
Jamie lannister
```

so I can query AD for sam's

Answer (score 0):

To have lastname and firstname you can do this:

```
$names = $string.split(",")
[array]::Reverse($names)
$names
```

So if I understood correctly, you want to skip the header (first line). Try changing the following:

```
Import-Csv C:\list.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name
```

(or increase '-Skip' amount according to how many lines you want to skip)

Comment: no i want to have names in order firstname and lastname

Comment: You can store the split string in variables as follows: $a,$b = $string.split(' ') - see updated answer

Comment: I tried

`Import-Csv C:\list.csv | 
foreach { 
$a,$b = $string.split(' ')
$_.Name = $b + ", " + $a
}
$_.name`


csv

`Name
snow,jon
starc,arya`

no luck

Comment: OK try this: $names = $string.split(",") and then add [array]::Reverse($names) and finally $names (i will add it in the answer for formatting)

Comment: i think ps v3 or later is required i get ` 
Cannot find an overload for "Reverse" and the argument count: "1".
At line:3 char:17
+ [array]::Reverse <<<< ($_.name)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest`

Comment: appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The question you have here to me reads a little vague, but I wanted to offer the below. If you specify the header of the CSV when you import it, you can output whatever Property you want, in whatever order:

```
$test = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\test.txt" -Header Last_Name,First_Name
$test | % {"$($_.First_Name) $($_.Last_Name)"}
```

Comment: I got that working, the challenge was it only has a header name.I use pso property if you want to know `Import-Csv c:\list.csv |
foreach{   
    $last,$first = $_.name -split ","
    new-object psobject -Property @{name = "$first,$last"}
} `

Answer (score 0):

It was

```
Import-Csv c:\list.csv |
foreach{   
    $last,$first = $_.name -split ","
    new-object psobject -Property @{name = "$first,$last"}
}
```